# Verifying RADIUS server is sending the correct certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, radius, debugging, 802.1

How can I see the TLS (SSL) certificates that my RADIUS server is using, to make sure it is sending the correct certificate and chain?

I am implementing 802.1x authentication with a RADIUS server, but I have [certificate acceptance problems on some supplicants (clients)](https://superuser.com/questions/1067152/trust-root-or-leaf-certificate-in-802-1x-setup). I would like to see the certificates sent by the server in an easy way, similar to how you use `openssl s_client` to debug TCP TLS traffic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`eapol_test`](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/testing_tools.html), which is part of [the `wpa_supplicant` package](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/). You need to download the source code and compile it with `make eapol_test` (it's not built by default). It should work at least on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X (not advertised as much, but I could compile and use it on the latter).

You create a configuration file ([some examples here](http://deployingradius.com/scripts/eapol_test/), but I could not find an overview of all options, I think [`src/eap_peer/eap_config.h`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/src/eap_peer/eap_config.h) contains some), and then run the tool:

```
./eapol_test -c <config file> -s <shared secret> -a <ip address of radius server>
```

In all the output you should see the TLS certificate pass by, but you can also dump them to a file by passing the `-o` option:

```
-o<server cert file> = Write received server certificate
                       chain to the specified file
```

If you specify the `ca_cert` option in the configuration file, the program will also do a verification of the sent chain, and you see the verification result in the output of the program (not in the file with dumped certificates).

Afterwards, you can also use [the `rad_eap_test` wrapper](http://www.eduroam.cz/rad_eap_test/rad_eap_test.html), which returns a status output compatible with Nagios.

Comment: Thanks for this! It's perfect timing; we're starting our 802.1X tests next week...